Удаление метки [dash]
Предлагаю удалить и запретить метку dash с неоднозначным кругом вопросов. На ru.stackoverflow.com она используется для слишком разноплановых вопросов - из того что видела:

потоковое видео, mpeg-dash -  для фронтендеров
фреймворк для визуализации данных на основе plotly - для питонистов
панель инструментов в Linux

Почему не использовать описание? - слишком разноплановые темы - это не сильно облегчит понимание и удобство поиска целевых вопросов.
В поисковике - при попытке разобраться в контексте - вообще криптовалюта Dash на первых строчках.
На stackoverflow.com метки dash вообще не существует, вместо этого - более специализированные - plotly-dash - для библиотеки Python и mpeg-dash - для видео.
Т.е. в итоге предлагаю - раскидать вопросы по соответствующим специализированным меткам и удалить.
Есть мнения, дополнительная информация, предложения или что-то неучтенное мною?
UPD: создала метки plotly-dash и mpeg-dash и раскидала по ним вопросы. На данный момент метка dash пустая.
[Заморожен запрос] - запрещать метки могут только сотрудники с очень длительной процедурой - обсуждать можно, но на ближайший результат не стоит надеяться.

Возможно стоит поправить заголовок вопроса, с учетом того что вы предлагаете "раскидать вопросы по соответствующим специализированным меткам и удалить", а не просто удалить )

@Kromster  "раскидать" уже не актуально - внаглую создала метки и сделала это сама раз предложила.  На данный момент метка dash пустая. Насчет остального - не сильно надеюсь что случится в ближайшее время.
